Urban fantasy book/saga about a boy with many phobias who found out he belonged to a group of people with powers
I picked a Spanish translation of this book up in the library 6 years ago but I can't remember the title or the author. I am pretty sure it was a male writer, though. The saga it belonged to had a very generic name consisting of the number of people in the group with powers, which I'm pretty sure were either 7, 11 or 12, and an adjective like "marvelous" "wonderful" "fabulous" something like that. What I remember is:

The protagonist was a teenage boy who had a lot of phobias diagnosed and found out he belonged to a group of people with different superpowers. There were either 7, 11 or 12 people like him that he had to recruit in order to kill the villain seven times.
Either him or one of his friends had powers relating to light and darkness.
In one of the continuations, there were flashbacks from a medieval era with another POV.
The humor and narration was very similar to pjo but in 3rd person.
One of the people he had to recruit was a cute girl who worked on a boat ship and he described her hands as calloused from working.
There was a scene in which a dirigible filled with helium exploded.
Having a phobia was described as being locked w a gorilla inside a cage.

If anyone knows this book, please let me know the title. I never finished the saga because my library didn't have them all and I can't stop thinking about it!!!

"The humor and narration was very similar to pjo but in 3rd person." I wasn't sure what you meant by "pjo." Was that a reference to Percy Jackson and the Olympians...?

Is this The Magnificent 12 series by Michael Grant...?

Book 1: The Call (2010)
Book 2: The Trap (2011)
Book 3: The Key (2012)
Book 4: The Power (2013)

According to the blurb on the Google Books page for the first book, The Call, the protagonist is Mack McAvoy, a 12-year-old boy with a long list of phobias. He receives a visit from a golem who informs him that he's one of twelve powerful children who must unite in order to save the world from the Pale Queen, a force of evil who's been around since medieval times:

Mack McAvoy is not an unlikely hero. He is an impossible hero! He is only twelve years old, he has a list of phobias as long as your arm, and he's a bully magnet. That is, until Mack is visited by a golem. The golem looks exactly like Mack, and has been sent to fill in for him while the real Mack sets out to save the world from the evil Pale Queen. To do so, he must assemble an elite team of twelve powerful children from all around the world. The first foe they face is Risky. Risky is pure evil. She gets it from her mother - the Pale Queen - a force of evil to be reckoned with since before medieval times.



At least the first three books have been translated into Spanish: La Llamada, La Trampa, and La Llave.
